# Azure Search and Cosmos DB with complex structures

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cognitive-search

I have something like this in CosmosDB:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Thomas",
    "countries": [
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Denmark"
      },
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Sweden"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Alberto",
    "countries": [
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Spain"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I can see that Azure search have a collection type, but not for complex structures. So I would have to flattened out countries into two different columns og type collection. Correct me if I am wrong here. I can also see there is a connector from Azure Search to Cosmos DB. Does this connector work with a scenario like above, or do you have to build your own indexer? Does it support complex types in anyway?

Answer (score 2):

Complex Types support in Azure Search is now generally available, including Cosmos DB indexer support. You should be able to try it out using the Import Data feature in the Azure portal.